# Must a word be binary (and never unary)?

Tags: memory-management, word-combinatorics

I understand that a computer memory sequential word must always include at least two bits so it must be binary and therefore cannot be unary.

Must a word be binary (and never unary)?
That is to ask; can there be a "unary" computer memory sequential word?

---

<sub>This question might relate to my other question - [Must a Turing machine tape be binary?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134900/must-a-turing-machine-tape-be-binary)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Machine words have fixed length. Denoting the length by $n$ and the base by $b$, each machine word has $b^n$ possible values, and so stores $\log_2 (b^n)$ bits of information.

A base can be binary or decimal and so forth; if $b=1$ then the machine word has a single possible value, and so stores no information. It would be useless.

Unary encoding is only relevant in contexts where the length is not fixed.

Comment: No. Decimal is base 10, binary is base 2, and so on.

Comment: `Unary encoding is only relevant in contexts where the length is not fixed.` This is a very interesting read for me; I never read about such situations anywhere, would you say it's part of **fringe theories** of computer science? Are there computers which at least theoretically work this way and could produce similar output to the one we can get with RAM modeled or Turing-Machine modeled computers?

Comment: It would be a folly to use unary encoding, since it’s exponentially less efficient than other encodings.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well that's not entirely true. Unary encoding is used in data compression for symbols where the expected frequency of the symbols follows a geometric distribution. See, for example, Golomb-Rice coding, which is used in inverted index compression, as well as many codecs like FLAC and MP4-ALS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding