# Are there words without fixed size length?

Tags: computation-models

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134947), Yuval Filmus wrote:

> Unary encoding is only relevant in contexts where the length is not fixed.

**Are there words without fixed size length?**
Is there a Computer Science theory which describes computers which can include such words in their memory cells (while at least some words are unary) and could the output of such computers be similar to that of RAM-modeled/Turing-modeled Turing-complete computers?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are asking.  Can you share a little background about your current thinking and your current understanding, so I can better address what you are trying to learn?  I'm not sure what you mean by "computing words".

Comment: I understand that computer memory cells host at least one word, which is a fixed-size, sequential piece of at least two bits of data; I try to understand if we could have a computer in which words are just not fix sized so that the memory would be many scattered words, at least some are unary and still the computer would work, however inefficient.

Comment: Words are an abstraction we use to interpret memory, but you can interpret it in another way.  You can certainly imagine such a thing.  I'm not sure what the question about that is...